# How can I speed up the load time of carrierwave / fog gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler, carrierwave, fog

I can see that carrierwave is one of the slowest loading* gems (c.2.5 seconds) which is annoying when running tests in particular. Fog is also slow loading and seems to be included in the carrierwave gem anyway. Is there a way to optimize either the fog or carrierwave installations to speed up loading?

*when I say 'loading' I mean when running rails/rake/rspec

fog 1.31.0
carrierwave 0.10.0
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2

Comment: Yeah, if you can use carrierwave + fog-aws instead of fog itself it should help. We've got more work to do around some of that (and would welcome the help), but not as much that can easily be done for end users I fear.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an effort to split fog into separate provider gems but unfortunately it will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest giving [carrierwave-aws](https://github.com/Tigraine/carrierwave-aws) a try. They claim significant load time improvements over Carrierwave, along with "Significantly smaller footprint"

```
Library Disk Space  Lines of Code   Boot Time   Runtime Deps    Develop Deps
fog       28.0M        33469        0.693       9               11
aws-sdk   4.4M         80017        0.098       3               8
```